# The Line code return Syntax Error with open file

Tags: python, syntax

I run a script with the code to open a file and it returns `SyntaxError`. The script is an open source script that I want to test.

```
with open(f"/home/mine/myfoldr/myapp.yml", "r") as file:
```

The line above returns the following error:

```
File "./startup.py", line 28
    with open(f"/home/mine/myfoldr/myapp.yml", 'r') as file:
                                            ^
```

I just don't understand what does it mean with `f"` here, after `open(f"...)`. Because normally it will be write something like below, without `f`.

```
with open("/home/mine/myfoldr/myapp.yml", "r") as file:
```

I think its not a typo because other line code in the script also..have the same style `f`, for example:

```
print(f"Which section do you want to change?"
      f"[Application/Controller/Database]")
```

Comment: Does it also throw an error if you remove the `f` that is before the file name?

Comment: it will thrw an error to the next line code that also hav 'f'... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `f` at the start of strings is called f-string, introduced with [PEP 489](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) starting at `Python 3.6`.

It is used for string formatting, similar to `.format()`. There are a lot of tutorials on it you can read. The basic example:

```
x = 22
print('this is {}'.format(x))
print(f'this is {x}')
```

Here, both lines will output the same resulting string `this is 22`.

---

You probably get the error because you are using a version older than `Python 3.6`, some version where f-strings are not supported.

To test the third-party code you will have to use a newer Python version or modify the code yourself (but this last options may be a lot of work and may introduce some unintentional errors).

Comment: i tried run the file  sudo python3 startup.py and it still return d same... in my env i have python3, 3.5, 3.6 ....

Comment: @chenoi can you try using `python3.6 startup.py`?

Comment: i tried that ..no more syntax error but now got module not found error...for example File "startup.py", line 10, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'   I tried reinstall again requirements.txt using pip3...but another modulenotfound ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'

Comment: @chenoi Careful: for which Python version is `pip3` installing the packages? It can be quite messy to use `pip` when you have more than 1 python version installed

Comment: Great Ralf.... thanks...for your support and guideline... thanks again... i will try to resolve it....at least i know...d issue is due to my python version that i need to apply 3.6 version